# Express js cors preflight request not successful despite enabling cors

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, cors, preflight

I am using a self signed ssl certificate (for now) to run an https server using express. Here is my app.js

```js
const express = require('express');
const BodyParser = require('body-parser');
const config = require('./config');
const Logger = require('./loaders/logger');
const cors = require('cors');
const fs = require('fs');
const https = require('https');
const app = express();
const router = express.Router();
const usersApi = require('./api/users');
const authMiddleWare = require('./middlewares/auth');

var whitelist = ['http://localhost:8080', 'https://somedomain.web.app']

var corsOptionsDelegate = function (req, callback) {
  var corsOptions;
  if (whitelist.indexOf(req.header('Origin')) !== -1) {
    corsOptions = { origin: true } // reflect (enable) the requested origin in the CORS response
  }else{
    corsOptions = { origin: false } // disable CORS for this request
  }
  callback(null, corsOptions) // callback expects two parameters: error and options
}

app.use(cors(corsOptionsDelegate));
app.use(BodyParser.json());
app.use('/user', usersApi);
app.get('/abc/:id', function (req, res, next) {
  return res.json({ foo: 'bar' });
});


async function startServer() {

  await require('./loaders').default({ expressApp: app });

  https.createServer({
    key: fs.readFileSync('server.key'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync('server.cert')
  },app).listen(config.port, err => {
    if (err) {
      Logger.error(err);
      process.exit(1);
      return;
    }
    Logger.info(`
      ################################################
      ️  Server listening on port: ${config.port} ️ 
      ################################################
    `);
  });
}

startServer();
```

When I try to access from my front end (vue js app using axios) on localhost:8080, it does not work if its running on remote server and I get this error:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://147.215.83.136/user/param' from origin 'http://localhost:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

But if same thing runs on localhost, it works!
With the vue js app deployed remotely, it also does not work and I get the same error.
Other things I tried are:

```js
app.use(cors());
app.options("*",cors());
app.use(cors({origin: "http://localhost:8080"}) // also tried putting https url of the vue app instead of this one. Still same result
```

So what is going on and why isn't it working(on mozilla or chrome)?

EDIT:
Network requests tab in chrome shows this:
[image]
[image]

Comment: can you check the response headers to the preflight

Comment: Not an answer at all but FYI, Express has it's own built-in JSON body parser these days, eg `app.use(express.json())`

Comment: @JaromandaX the chrome network inspector tab does not show any response headers for the preflight request. Also if I try to put a console.log in corsoptiondelegate, function, that does not get logged. Perhaps the request is getting blocked at the browser itself?

Comment: Nice to know @Phil

Comment: Do you see an `OPTIONS` request being made in your browser's _Network_ console? If so, what is the response like for that? Is there a response at all or an error message from the browser?

Comment: @Phil NO i don't see any OPTIONS request in my browsers Network console. Check attached screenshots in edited answer.

Comment: That just looks like your URL is wrong / unresolvable

Comment: @Phil nope. I can hit that url in my browser(though that shows connection not protected page)

Answer (score -1):

Also be carefull to not mix content on https site with content generated from api request on http,
As there is no way to fix this later